# Should one encrypt a DTP communication when HDFS is already encrypted?

Tags: hadoop, encryption, hdfs, sasl, bigdata

Is encrypting a **Hadoop Data Transfer Protocol** (DTP) communication (which is an *in-transit encryption*) redundant with **HDFS Transparent Encryption** (which is considered an *at-rest encryption*) when the latest is already configured on the cluster?

In other words, is there any benefit to using a **SASL handshake** wrapping when the HDFS end-to-end encryption is enabled, or I am missing something here?